# Ruby - rails - read only text value form input

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I print simple text to be a form value and make it non editable? 
I am not looking for

```
<%= text_field_tag :something, nil, :readonly => true %>
```

I want it without a read only input box. 
Like html  and still get posted via the form.

```
<a id="something"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag ... %>
<%= your_variable_here_with_whatever_format_you_want %>
```

Answer (score 0):

render_field(field, prefix, options.merge(:hide_description => true, :readonly => true))

Where render_field is the following:

# Returns html
  def render_field(field, prefix = "", options = {})
    hidden = field.fetch("HIDDEN", false)
    return if hidden
    field_type = field["TYPE_KIND"].upcase
    return "Unkown field type #{field_type}" unless %w(C N D G P).include?(field_type)

```
send("render_#{field_type.downcase}_type", *[field, prefix, options])
```

end